What do you call someone who doesn't like celebrating holidays?
The answer doesn't have to be specific to any religion or faith group, or even any calendar whether it's the Gregorian calendar or any others. I was thinking about similar words like scrooge or humbug but those words are usually particular to one holiday or faith of some sort. So is there a word like that in the English language?

I don't think there's anything specific to holidays. There are words like "party-pooper" for people who don't like celebrating in general.

Surely there does not have to be a word for everything.  As a matter of a fact there exists a word 'festophobia'.  It seems to apply mainly to dreading an avalanche of celebrations, as there is in the late autumn and winter.

Though it pertains to Christmas the term Grinch is always understood.

There's such a range of holidays. Lots of people hate Christmas but like Halloween, and vice versa. And other even more niche events (German-American Day, village fetes and state fairs, Beltane, Highland Games, Talk Like A Pirate Day, Gathering of the Juggalos...) You want a word for someone who doesn't like having any fun, or someone who refuses traditional holidays, or prefers to do their own thing spontaneously, or what?

@StuartF I was thinking more someone who refuses traditional holidays and likes to do their own thing.

holiday naysayers

You can find the word holiday-averse in many sources including news articles.
